# Digitalocean: Rails does not load assets in production mode

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails, assets, digital-ocean

I have a problem on Digitalocean. Rails does not load assets in production mode. These are the errors in my `nginx.error.log`:

> 2018/05/15 07:36:15 [error] xxxx#xxxx: *287 open()
>   "/home/deploy/my-app/public/assets/application-ebfec4dd0d514096e0a404ee9a54f2924a01ee7755b16d05a38e8bca7c442a34.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx(ip), server:
>   , request: "GET
>   /assets/application-ebfec4dd0d514096e0a404ee9a54f2924a01ee7755b16d05a38e8bca7c442a34.css
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "yourselforderfood.com", referrer:
>   "http://my-site.com/"
>
> 2018/05/15 07:36:15 [error]
>   xxxx#xxxx: *285 open()
>   "/home/deploy/my-app/public/assets/application-86cc2a7aed5b41249ff7d5436f7a08df58d9f71a414af5794cb82f6c35a00567.js"
>   failed (2: No such file or directory), client: xx.xx.xx.xx(ip), server:
>   , request: "GET
>   /assets/application-86cc2a7aed5b41249ff7d5436f7a08df58d9f71a414af5794cb82f6c35a00567.js
>   HTTP/1.1", host: "yourselforderfood.com", referrer:
>   "http://my-site.com/"

I have checked that the files in `/home/deploy/my-app/public/assets/` are there.

Why do I get these errors if the files exist?

Comment: Can you do an `ls -la /home/deploy/my-app/public/assets/application-ebfec4dd0d514096e0a404ee9a54f2924a01ee7755b16d05a38e8bca7c442a34.css` to see what kind of permissions the files have? Are they readable by the nginx process?

Comment: Permissions on .css file are "-rw-rw-r-- 1 deploy deploy". What should I do?

Comment: What about `/home/deploy/my-app/public/assets` and as what user is nginx running?

Comment: Assets have this permissions "drwxrwxr-x  4 deploy deploy". My user is "deploy". If this is not the answer to your question, how can I check my nginx user?

Comment: js file that I have in **app/my-app/current/public/assets/** is different from js file in **my-app/public/assets**. What should I do?

Comment: `ps -eo pid,comm,euser,group | grep nginx` shows you what user & group nginx runs as. Can you add nginx to the group deploy and change the permissions on the deployed files to 755 and see if that helps?

Comment: How can I do that?